# Gif Animation not playing in Kivy App

Tags: python, animation, gif, kivy

I am writing a kivy application, a game, which has an animated gif at the top which should play on a loop, as it does in finder etc. When it loads into the kivy gui it only shows one frame. I am new to kivy and would appreciate some help with this issue. I am using the .kv file to load the image:

```
    Image:
    source: 'spaceshipgif.gif'
    allow_stretch: True
```

I have studied the documentation on the kivy website and searched around but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't remember exactly what the gif playing status is - they should work in principle, but some of our providers are better than others at it. As I remember it might work better if you compile kivy with PIL as the image provider. I think some of these problems can be caused by technically incorrect gif files, which aren't handled well by the default provider, but I'm not sure about this.

A better solution is to instead put the frames of the .gif as images in a zip file, and set the path to this zip as the image path in your widget. Kivy will automatically animate them for you, including making it easy to change the animation rate (or pause it), without being limited by problems with gif files.

Comment: The zip file worked great! But now when I resize the window the image turns black, is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Are you able to report it at kivy's github repo, with a simple example?

Comment: try checking for when the screen resizes and refresh the screen anytime that the screen is resized.

Comment: Hi @inclement how do I use a different image provider as I am having a similar issue. How do I check the one currently being used?

Thanks

Comment: Be aware, the frames should be named in format file_name-001, 002,.. 010,.. 100,.. 150 otherwise sorting will go wrong and frames will rendered in wrong order.